# FFmpeg unable to stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have a simple http server for incoming MPEG stream and I'm trying to stream video from another machine on the same network. It works using ffmpeg like this

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f mpeg1video http://myaddress.com:port
```

But from one specific computer ffmpeg refuses to stream and I can't find out why. All I can get is this output:

```
ffmpeg version 0.7.8, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
built on Sep 16 2012 09:30:22 with gcc 4.5.3

configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --shlibdir=/usr/lib 
--mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --cc=i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc 
--disable-static --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter 
--disable-stripping --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-network 
--disable-vaapi --disable-ffplay --disable-vdpau --disable-indev=v4l 
--disable-indev=oss --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=oss 
--disable-altivec --disable-avx --cpu=atom --enable-hardcoded-tables

libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
```

Comment: Yes this is complete output nothing is streaming at all. And also sorry that I've put this into wrong forum.

Answer (score 1):

Your ffmpeg build is compiled with `--disable-network` which I assume is the problem.